# Passing hexadecimal color values from Xcode to Javascript

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios5, hex

I am trying to pass a Hexadecimal color value from objectiveC to Javascript. I am displaying a graph and I am trying to pass the color to javascript so that I dont need to hardcode it in my html page.

Here is what I do -

In my .m File,

```
NSArray *colorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"FFFFFF",@"000000", nil];

colorString = [[colorArray valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

In my webViewDidFinishLoad function,

```
[graphView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"methodName1([%@])", colorString]];
```

However, the javascript is not able to accept the values.

In my Javascript function, what should I do to accept the values - FFFFFF and 000000 so that I can use them.

I am trying to use the colors like this -

```
line1.Set('chart.colors', ['FF0000', '000000']);
```

where instead of giving the hexadecimal values there, I would like to get it from objC.

Update -

Here is the javascript function I use -

```
function methodName1(val)
{
   alert("hi");
}
```

However, the function does not even get called.. I feel the issue is with the way I pass the values...

It would be great if someone could help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling

```
methodName1([FFFFFF,000000]); // will fail since FFFFFF is not defined
```

But you want

```
methodName1(['FFFFFF','000000']);
```

Comment: how would I call this from objc? would I do this - [graphView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"methodName1('[%@]')", colorString]];

Comment: well.. that worked!!  [graphView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"methodName1('[%@]')", colorString]]; putting the '' before the string passed the value...

Comment: You need to make sure to quote each individual argument. Try `colorstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@'", [colorArray componentsJoinedByString:@"','"]];`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add an "#" character before each color.

Comment: And, yeah...

`colorString = [colorArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];`

would be enough.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. however, I am still facing the issue.. I have updated my question with the function I use...

Comment: Also, if I pass even string like NSArray *colorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b", nil]; the function does not get called..